# Неясная переменная в обработчике события resize в коде MDN

Tags: javascript

Есть код (взято с MDN [обработка события resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/resize))
    (function() {

```
  window.addEventListener("resize", resizeThrottler, false);

  var resizeTimeout;
  function resizeThrottler() {
  // ignore resize events as long as an actualResizeHandler execution is in 
  //the queue
    if ( !resizeTimeout ) {
    resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      resizeTimeout = null;
      actualResizeHandler();

      // The actualResizeHandler will execute at a rate of 15fps
    }, 66);
  }
}

function actualResizeHandler() {
  // handle the resize event
  ...
}

}());
```

Вопрос. Зачем нужна переменная resizeTimeout?

Comment: По названию ясно. В целом - это техника [`Debouncing`](http://onedev.net/post/480).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Она служит флагом, показывающим (когда не `null` и не `undefined`), что мы ждем выполнения заказанного `actualResizeHandler` и не хотим заказывать его еще раз.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что пока мы ждем выполнения заказанного actualResizeHandler, числовой идентификатор таймера не равен null и событие не обрабатывается в указанном интервале времени?

Comment: @AlexanderKorinskiy да

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек. Я всю голову сломал. Очень благодарен, потому как из таких мелочей складывается бесценный опыт.

Comment: @AlexanderKorinskiy На здоровье. Слева галочка - щёлк :). Успехов.